# how to call an akka http route in another akka http route using akka http client using docker?

Tags: docker, scala, akka, akka-http

i have two Akka HTTP servers both running on docker and on separate ports

i have used **sbt native package** manager to create dockerfiles

here is the docker-compose of projectA

```
  akkahttpservice:
    image: projectA-service:0.0.1
    container_name: projectA-service-container
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
```

here is the docker-compose of projectB

```
akkahttpservice:
    image: projectB-service:0.0.1
    container_name: projectB-service-container
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
```

here is the output of `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS          PORTS                                                                                  NAMES
71a58c080e7c   projectA-service:0.0.1   "/opt/docker/bin/not…"   5 minutes ago   Up 5 minutes    8084/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8085->8085/tcp, :::8085->8085/tcp                                    projectA-service-container
c08f5700ce3d   projectB-service:0.0.1          "/opt/docker/bin/int…"   22 hours ago    Up 28 minutes   0.0.0.0:8083->8083/tcp, :::8083->8083/tcp                                              projectB-service-container
```

i want to call projectB route in projectA using akka http client

here is the route of projectB

```
def getAdminToken: server.Route =
    path("get-admin-token") {
    post {
  entity(as[JsValue]) {
            json =>
              val userName = json.asJsObject.fields("userName").convertTo[String]
              val userPwd = json.asJsObject.fields("userPwd").convertTo[String]
complete("got the details")
        }
   }
}
```

here is the code of projectA in which i want to call projectB route

```
def addUserInKeyCloak: server.Route = {
    path("add-user-in-keycloak") {
      post {
        entity(as[NotaryUser]) {
          notaryUser =>
            val adminUrl = "http://0.0.0.0:8083/get-admin-token"
        val jsonStr =
          s"""{
             |     "userName":"admin",
             |   "userPwd":"admin"
             |  }""".stripMargin
val request = HttpRequest(HttpMethods.POST, adminUrl, Nil, HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, jsonStr.stripMargin.parseJson.toString()))
        val responseFuture = Http(context.system).singleRequest(request)
        complete("result from future")
            
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I have tried with

```
val adminUrl = "http://0.0.0.0:8083/get-admin-token"
```

got an exception

```
Tcp command [Connect(0.0.0.0:8083,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed because of java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Tcp command [Connect(0.0.0.0:8083,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed because of java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused)
```

and I tried with different URL

```
val adminUrl = "http://projectB-service-container:8083/get-admin-token"
```

then i got another exception

```
Tcp command [Connect(docker-interpret-auth-container:8083,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed because of java.net.UnknownHostException: projectB-service-container (akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Tcp command [Connect(projectB-service-container:8083,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed because of java.net.UnknownHostException: projectB-service-container)
```

The code is working fine without using docker all the above exceptions occurred when running both on docker using docker-compose

the above code is also working fine with postman and curl when running on docker using docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to use a route with the host `0.0.0.0` will just attempt to make a request to the port inside of the same container, which isn't what you're looking for. Your error is `Connection refused` because the applications are running in different containers, so they can't reach each other using host `0.0.0.0`. In order to access another running container using Docker Compose, reference the name of the service as the host, such as in the following `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.3"
services:
  akkahttpservicea:
    image: projectA-service:0.0.1
    container_name: projectA-service-container
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
  akkahttpserviceb:
    image: projectB-service:0.0.1
    container_name: projectB-service-container
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
```

For example, in projectA, make a call projectB with

```scala
val adminUrl = "http://akkahttpserviceb:8083/get-admin-token"
```